# Webpack not recognizing CSS files even with the appropriate loaders installed

Tags: css, webpack, webpack-5, webpack-loader

webpack doesn't seem to recognize my CSS files even with the appropriate loaders installed...

**webpack.config.js**:

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = env => {
    let devType = env.production || false;
    console.log(devType);

    return {
        mode: devType ? "production" : "development",

        entry: "./src/js/app.js",

        output: {
            filename: "js/app.bundle.js",
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, "docs"),
            assetModuleFilename: "imgs/[name][ext]",
            clean: true
        },

        devServer: {
            static: {
                directory: path.resolve(__dirname, "./docs")
            },
            port: 5001
        },

        module: {
            rules: [{
                    test: /\.html/g,
                    use: ["html-loader"]
                },

                {
                    test: /\.(svg|ico|webp|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
                    type: "asset/resource"
                },

                {
                    test: /\.css/g,
                    use: [
                        devType ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : "style-loader",
                        {
                            loader: "css-loader"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },

        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                filename: "index.html",
                template: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.html")
            }),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: "css/main.css"
            })
        ]

    };
};
```

**package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build:dev": "webpack --watch",
    "build:prod": "webpack --watch --env production",
    "start:dev": "webpack serve --open",
    "start:prod": "webpack serve --open --env production"

  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "bunee",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "html-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.4.5",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.64.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.5.0"
  }
}
```

**app.js**:

```
import "../css/normalize.css";
import "../css/app.css";

console.log("bunee");
```

**Error**:
[image]

I do have to mention one more thing, Everything works completely fine if only one CSS file is imported in *app.js*. The problem only occurs when I try to import multiple CSS files.

If I haven't made myself clear, Please feel free to ask me questions.

Comment: Aren't you meant to import CSS into a variable?

Comment: @connexo That's optional... regardless, importing CSS into a variable still produces the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my mistake, Here's the culprit. [image]

Yes, the regexp I used was the problem (*face palms*). I replaced it with `/(\.css)$/` and everything worked fine. If someone in the future finds this helpful, you better thank me. I lost way too many hairs on my scalp trying to solve this dumb mistake.